CRITICAL: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer in reviewboard
Am getting CRITICAL: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer when i do
rbt post -o in reviewboard

Resolved: This is because the diffs had SQL keywords in a patteren such that it is vulnerable for SQL Injection
like if the diff has:
"foo foo foo UNION SELECT * from foo foo"
This diff will get the above error.
To Resolve:
change that line to :
"foo foo foo UNION /"
+" SELECT * from foo foo"
You can write it in next line using escape quotes.
